# Scapy: failed to set hardware filter to promiscuous mode: A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: python, windows, scapy

I am trying to send an ICMP packet with python scapy like this:

```
request_packet = IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP(type="echo-request")
send(request_packet)
```

but when running the code the following error appears:

```
OSError: \Device\NPF_{5E5248B6-F793-4AAF-BA07-269A904D1D3A}: failed to set hardware filter to promiscuous mode: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

I am on Windows 10 and using a wired internet connection. How can i fix this?